# Plot day of year on y-axis but label as month-day in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with this dataset with 3 variables: `year`, `upwelling`, and `day`:

```
structure(list(year = c(1982, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1985, 
1985, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 
1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1996, 
1996, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 
2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 
2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2018, 
2018, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020), upwelling = c("First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", 
"First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", "Last Day", "First Day", 
"Last Day"), day = c(149L, 193L, 152L, 225L, 153L, 251L, 169L, 
193L, 133L, 210L, 159L, 194L, 181L, 198L, 129L, 219L, 152L, 197L, 
154L, 360L, 147L, 194L, 170L, 214L, 122L, 242L, 137L, 192L, 165L, 
185L, 167L, 303L, 179L, 214L, 148L, 237L, 174L, 200L, 166L, 226L, 
129L, 206L, 138L, 196L, 148L, 199L, 158L, 200L, 140L, 202L, 149L, 
247L, 178L, 186L, 177L, 195L, 167L, 193L, 140L, 223L, 163L, 223L, 
129L, 188L, 143L, 186L, 122L, 156L, 132L, 203L, 141L, 204L, 140L, 
219L, 119L, 198L, 154L, 192L)), row.names = c(NA, -78L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I made a line plot as below, with y-axis being the day of the year.

```
 df %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = year, y = day, col = upwelling, group = upwelling)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1982, 1990, 1995,
                                2000, 2005, 2010, 2015,
                                2020))
```

[Image of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71H1W.png)

How do I label the y-axis `month-day` format, instead of day of year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how will your final plot would look since you have data for different years but this might be a step towards it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Change day-year to date and then month-day format.
data <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(day, year), '%j %Y'), 
         date = format(date, '%b %d')) 
  
ggplot(data, aes(x = year, y = date, col = upwelling, group = upwelling)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1982, 1990, 1995,
                                2000, 2005, 2010, 2015,
                                2020)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = data$date[seq(1, nrow(data), 3)])
```

Since y-axis will be crowded I used `data$date[seq(1, nrow(data), 3)]` to display every 3rd label.

Comment: I feel like this might help, but don't know how, `paste(rep(month.abb, each=2), rep(c("01", "15")))`

Answer (score 1):

Note! this doesn't answer your question completely yet!

...

One problem is, Month+Day don't fall on the same Year+Day every year (e.g. Leap Year)

...

To figure out the date for day 189 of the year 2016:

```
as.Date(189, origin = "2016-01-01")
[1] "2016-07-08"
```

Applied to your data set:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$day, origin = paste(df$year, "01-01", sep="-"))
```

Comment: I made the `date` column, as above, and tried to label the y-axis with `date` but ggplot kept on complaining.